# Open a closed workbook to a specific sheet based of a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent to much time trying to figure this out and would appreciate some help.

I would like to open a closed workbook based off a cell value (eg A1) containing a file path and have it open up to the sheet matching another cell (eg A2).

for example A1 = C:\User\TEST.xls
and A2= Sheet3

I would like a button that opens C:\User[TEST.xls]Sheet3
Here's what I've got so far:

```
    Sub OpenSesame()

    Dim ClosedBook As Workbook

    Set ClosedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.Range("ClosedBookFile").Value)
 'ClosedBookFile is a named cell

    ClosedBook.Sheets(*DYNAMIC CELL VALUE*).Activate

    Range("A1").Select

    End Sub
```

What can I put instead of *dynamic cell value* to open to a specific sheet or am I barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a good idea to refer the Name of the worksheet as a variable and refer it later. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenSesame()

    Dim ClosedBook          As Workbook
    Dim nameOfWorksheet     As String
    Dim pathToOpen          As String

    With Worksheets(1)
        nameOfWorksheet = .Range("A10") 'for example
        pathToOpen = .Range("ClosedBookFile")
    End With

    Set ClosedBook = Workbooks.Open(pathToOpen)
    ClosedBook.Worksheets(nameOfWorksheet).Activate
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Furthermore, it is a good practice to refer the worksheet, whenever you are referring to a range. Thus, `With Worksheets(1)` refers the first worksheet in your current workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Along @Vityata lines, I'd add you need explict reference of which workbook the worksheet with data belongs to, and avoid implicit reference to the currently active workbook

here's a *compressed* code with what above

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenSesame()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheetWithFileInfoName") ' reference worksheet holding info of workbook and worksheet to activate

        Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.Range("ClosedBookFile").value).Worksheets(.Range("A2").value).Activate ' open wanted workbook and activate wanted worksheet

        'from now on the wanted worksheet in the wanted workbook is the active one

        Range("A1").Select ' almost always not needed
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @LyallLyle, any feedback?